# Google My Business - Tracking Reviews for Bulk Uploads

Tags: google-my-business

We are managing a client which has a number of locations. We added these to GMB using the bulk upload option. However, due to this, we are not getting email updates when the client receives a review. We called Google Support and they said that if you bulk upload locations, you do not receive emails when a review is left. Has anyone else had this issue and if so, have you discovered a good way to track reviews?